# How to view a component in onPress of React-Native-Paper Chip component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I want to show a Add button when I click Chip's onPress. The component I want to display is onPressChip() function. This is my code.

```
const Item = ({title}) => (
  <View>
    <Chip onPress={() => onPressChip()} style={{margin: 'auto'}}>
      {title}
    </Chip>
  </View>
);

const onPressChip = () => {
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse', marginTop: 10}}>
    <Button
      disabled={false}
      icon={'plus'}
      mode="contained"
      onPress={() => onClickAddButton()}
      color={'#0AB155'}
      style={{left: 0, marginTop: 5}}>
      {'Add'}
    </Button>
  </View>;
};


const GradingList = ({DATA}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.name} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default GradingList;
```

But it does not work. Please help.

Comment: Where you want to show button?

Comment: @JatinBhuva I want to show the button after flat list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take one boolean state variable based on that you can manage the view or hide button:

```
const[isButtonVisible,setIsButtonVisible]=useState(false)
const Item = ({title}) => (
  <View>
    <Chip onPress={() => setIsButtonVisible(!isButtonVisible)} style={{margin: 'auto'}}>
      {title}
    </Chip>
  </View>
);

const onPressChip = () => {
 return( <View style={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse', marginTop: 10}}>
    <Button
      disabled={false}
      icon={'plus'}
      mode="contained"
      onPress={() => onClickAddButton()}
      color={'#0AB155'}
      style={{left: 0, marginTop: 5}}>
      {'Add'}
    </Button>
  </View>)
};


const GradingList = ({DATA}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.name} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
      {isButtonVisible&&onPressChip()}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default GradingList;
```

This will add a button after all flatlist data is shown.

Comment: Let me know it works or not.